# What's the benefit to use VS2012 instead of VS2010 when using Tridion 2013

Tags: 2013, c#

I know VS2012 is able to use .NET framework 4.5. VS2010 can handle till .NET 4.0. I've seen the changelog between the frameworks, but is there any advantage according the use of Tridion 2013 when using framework 4.5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other than V2012 being a superior product to VS2010 enabling the developer to be more effective, there is no advantage specific to Tridion TOM.NET-related or Content Delivery-related development.

Answer (score 3):

The main advantage I can see is that Visual Studio 2013 has native integration with Git and Visual Studio online, which in fact are very robust features for modern software development.

Answer (score 2):

One advantage you would have in using VS2012 (or up) is that you can use the .NET framework 4.5, now for most Template Building Blocks and Event Handlers (using the TOM.NET API), there isn't much if anything at all that would be an advantage for you.

So unless you require the new features of 4.5 (I remember we needed it for something in the [Template Building Blocks](https://github.com/bkoopman/tri/tree/master/content-management/Sdl.Web.Templating) for the [SDL Tridion Reference Implementation](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/reference_implementation.aspx), but I forgot what it was), you would be equally good off with using the .NET 4.0 framework. With regards to which version of Visual Studio you should use, there I would be tempted to go for the latest at all times (although personally I didn't bother to upgrade from VS2012 to VS2013 yet at the time of writing this, but will soon when I get my new laptop ;o).